# Send a collection of data from .json file when a internet connection reconnects from esp8266 (Nodemcu)

Tags: esp8266, micropython, esp8266wifi

I have an esp8266 in a car recolecting a bunch of data, and I would like to send it when I come to my wifi connection at my home, actually, I have much access points between my daily route to my job and school, with different credentials.

In order to send the data quickly as possible I would like to send the data when some of the access points is reached.

How can I reach that goal? It is possible with micropython and an esp8266? Is there a better sollution for this?

I tried with mobile internet but is much expensive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this the esp8266 has a memory for saving the data.

```
// FileSystem Setup
  Serial.println(F("\n\nFile System Setup.."));
  if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
    if (!SPIFFS.exists(filename)) {
      SPIFFS.format();
      fa = SPIFFS.open(filename, "w");
      Serial.println("New File Created!");
    } else {
      fa = SPIFFS.open(filename, "a");
    }
    Serial.println(F("Setup Complted!"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Setup ERROR!"));
  }
```

Next when you reach the access point and the internet is connected after receiving the ping. Start sending the data from the file.

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying in a NodeMcu so i think that I'll use this idea to. :)